# How to import a service from another module in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-module

**Tech**: using angular 6, angular cli and typescript.

**Scenario**:

I have an **app module** and a **core module**

I want my app modules components to use the services from my core module.

**My core module contains a list of services:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Services
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

**This is my app module:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Modules
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

// Sections
import { COMPONENTS } from './components/index';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    COMPONENTS
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Note:** As you can see, I'm importing the CoreModule.

**This is my component from the app module (its calling the core module to get the AuthService):**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// This Auth Service import not working (says service not exported)
import { AuthService } from '../../core/core.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html'
})
export class ContactComponent {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}
}
```

**Issue**: I'm trying to import a service into my app modules component called contact component like so:

```
import { AuthService } from '../../core/core.module';
```

**Error I get:**

Service not an exported member of core module.

**Outcome:** I want my contact component from app module to import the core module service called AuthService.

Comment: What does your service look like? (Just the declaration)

Comment: Can you repo this is a small test stackblitz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you'd imported your `CoreModule` in `AppModule` where you'd also decalred your `ContactComponent` (seems in `COMPONENTS`), both **service** and **component** belong to the same **Module** here, so they can see each other. What'll have to do in your `ContactComponent` is merely **import the service  `AuthService` from its real location (not `../../core/core.module` )**.

```
import { AuthService } from ' <...>/auth.service';
```

Comment: You should not have to export a service?

Comment: @DeborahK How come ? you should not or you cannot ?

Comment: You should not need to. See the example of a core module here: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module Notice that it only exports components, not services.

Comment: @DeborahK, is that was the default behavior of angular or changed recently? Thank you very much indeed for the tip.

Comment: AFAIK, we've never needed to export services. Adding them to the providers array registers them with one of the application injectors. The injector then manages the instance. Exporting it doesn't do anything.

Comment: My god, many thanks ! I deleted that part from the answer, thank you indeed @DeborahK

Comment: @DeborahK whats the point of me putting the services in a core module, I might as well put them in the app module directly?

Comment: @AngularM Correct. There really is no point of using a core module anymore, especially with the new `providedIn` property of the `Injectable` decorator (new in v6). There is no need to register services in modules **AT ALL**. And yea, the StyleGuide needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If the module is properly imported in the root module, I think that if you add "export ... from ..." to your mymodule.module.ts:

```
import { MystuffService } from file 'mystuff.service'. 
export { MystuffService } from file 'mystuff.service'.
```

Then you can import your service:

```
import { MystuffService } from 'mymodule.module'
```